# Como documentar códigos em SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, documentação

Quando escrevo códigos em R, a maneira correta de documentar é no próprio código, em forma de comentários iniciados com uma marcação especial `#'`.

```
#' Add together two numbers.
#' 
#' @param x A number.
#' @param y A number.
#' @return The sum of \code{x} and \code{y}.
#' @examples
#' add(1, 1)
#' add(10, 1)
add <- function(x, y) {
  x + y
}
```

Depois existe uma ferramenta chamada `roxygen` que transforma esses comentários do código em um arquivo de documentação.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Esse formato, mantém a documentação próxima do código, deixando muito mais fáceis as suas atualizações. Além disso, é possível produzir documentos padronizados de documentação.

**Minha pergunta é: Como fazer algo parecido com isso para o SQL (especificamente para SQL Server)?**

Comment: Realmente essa é uma questão interessante. Eu não conheço nenhuma ferramenta parecida com a que você usa. Fiz algumas pesquisas há muito tempo sobre isso e não encontrei. Pensei em uma solução paliativa que seria usar `markdown` dentro do SQL. E salvar um código como `.md` e outro no formato que você precisa. Lhe atende? ------

Comment: Já deve ter cruzado com este link mas aqui vai http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-doc/

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Essa pergunta "[How do you document your databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/515)" do [dba.stackexchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com) tem algumas respostas interessantes.

Algumas das respostas aconselham usar as ferramentas:

- [SchemaSpy](http://schemaspy.sourceforge.net/): baseada em Java (requer Java 5 ou superior) que analisa os metadados de um esquema em um banco de dados e gera uma representação visual do que em um formato de navegador-exibível.
- [SchemaCrawler](http://sualeh.github.io/SchemaCrawler/): produz um arquivo de texto com todos os objetos esquema de banco de dados.
- [ApexSQL](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_doc.aspx): documenta os bancos de dados SQL Servers, cubos SSAS, relatórios SSRS e pacotes SSIS. Ele cria a documentação do banco de dados em uma variedade de formatos, incluindo a ajuda compilada (.CHM), HTML, PDF e MS Word. Além disso, o processo de documentação pode ser agendada e executar autônoma. Se escolher esse aconselho a ver essa [parte](http://solutioncenter.apexsql.com/document-sql-databases-automatically/) da documentação.
- [SQL Power Doc](https://sqlpowerdoc.codeplex.com/): coleção de scripts e módulos do Windows PowerShell que descobrem, documentam e diagnosticam instâncias do SQL Server e suas configurações subjacentes do sistema operacional Windows.
- [Data Dictionary Creator](http://datadictionary.codeplex.com/): aplicativo que ajuda a documentar bancos de dados SQL Server. Ele armazena todas as informações em Propriedades estendidas, por isso é mais fácil manter a documentação em sincronia com o banco de dados como ele muda.

Essa [resposta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1576) também parece uma boa solução, para o SQL Server ele usa as propriedade estendidas e um script do PowerShell, assim gera scripts de criação de tabela para uma única tabela ou para todas as tabelas no esquema dbo. Nesse script contém um `Create table` de comando, chaves primárias e índices. Chaves estrangeiras são adicionadas como comentários. As propriedades estendidas de tabelas e colunas de tabela são adicionadas como comentários. O script dele está ajustado ao estilo de codificação pessoal, sem colações individuais para colunas individuais e atualmente requer Sql Server Authentication.

Na [resposta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/1576) ele mostra o código completo para transformar as propriedades estendidas em um bom documento antigo ASCII (BTW é válido sql para recriar suas tabelas):

```
function Get-ScriptForTable
{
    param (
        $server, 
        $dbname,
        $user,
        $password,
        $filter
    )

[System.reflection.assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo") | out-null
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo")  | out-null

$conn = new-object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection" 
$conn.ServerInstance = $server
$conn.LoginSecure = $false
$conn.Login = $user
$conn.Password = $password
$conn.ConnectAsUser = $false
$srv = New-Object "Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server" $conn

$Scripter = new-object ("Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Scripter")
#$Scripter.Options.DriAll = $false
$Scripter.Options.NoCollation = $True
$Scripter.Options.NoFileGroup = $true
$scripter.Options.DriAll = $True
$Scripter.Options.IncludeIfNotExists = $False
$Scripter.Options.ExtendedProperties = $false
$Scripter.Server = $srv

$database = $srv.databases[$dbname]
$obj = $database.tables

$cnt = 1
$obj | % {

    if (! $filter -or  $_.Name -match $filter)
    {
        $lines = @()
        $header = "---------- {0, 3} {1, -30} ----------"  -f $cnt, $_.Name
        Write-Host $header 

        "/* ----------------- {0, 3} {1, -30} -----------------"  -f $cnt, $_.Name
        foreach( $i in $_.ExtendedProperties)
        {
            "{0}: {1}" -f $i.Name, $i.value
        }
        ""
        $colinfo = @{}
        foreach( $i in $_.columns)
        {
            $info = ""
            foreach ($ep in $i.ExtendedProperties)
            {
                if ($ep.value -match "`n")
                {
                    "----- Column: {0}  {1} -----" -f $i.name, $ep.name
                    $ep.value
                }
                else
                {
                    $info += "{0}:{1}  " -f $ep.name, $ep.value
                }
            }
            if ($info)
            {
                $colinfo[$i.name] =  $info
            }
        }
        ""
        "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM {0}" -f $_.Name
        "SELECT * FROM {0} ORDER BY 1" -f $_.Name
        "--------------------- {0, 3} {1, -30} ----------------- */" -f $cnt, $_.Name
        ""
        $raw = $Scripter.Script($_)
        #Write-host $raw
        $cont = 0
        $skip = $false 
        foreach ($line in $raw -split "\r\n")
        {
            if ($cont -gt 0)
            {
                if ($line -match "^\)WITH ")
                {
                    $line = ")"
                }
                $linebuf += ' ' + $line -replace " ASC", ""
                $cont--
                if ($cont -gt 0) { continue }
            }
            elseif ($line -match "^ CONSTRAINT ")
            {
                $cont = 3
                $linebuf = $line
                continue
            }
            elseif ($line -match "^UNIQUE ")
            {
                $cont = 3
                $linebuf = $line
                $skip = $true
                continue
            }
            elseif ($line -match "^ALTER TABLE.*WITH CHECK ")
            {
                $cont = 1
                $linebuf = "-- " + $line
                continue
            }
            elseif ($line -match "^ALTER TABLE.* CHECK ")
            {
                continue
            }
            else
            {
                $linebuf = $line
            }
            if ($linebuf -notmatch "^SET ")
            {
                if ($linebuf -match "^\)WITH ")
                {
                    $lines += ")"
                }
                elseif ($skip)
                {
                    $skip = $false
                }
                elseif ($linebuf -notmatch "^\s*$")
                {
                    $linebuf = $linebuf -replace "\]|\[", ""
                    $comment = $colinfo[($linebuf.Trim() -split " ")[0]]
                    if ($comment) { $comment = ' -- ' + $comment }
                    $lines += $linebuf + $comment
                }
            }
        }
        $lines += "go"
        $lines += ""
        $block = $lines -join "`r`n"
        $block
        $cnt++
        $used = $false
        foreach( $i in $_.Indexes)
        {
            $out = ''
            $raw = $Scripter.Script($i)
            #Write-host $raw
            foreach ($line in $raw -split "\r\n")
            {
                if ($line -match "^\)WITH ")
                {
                    $out += ")"
                }
                elseif ($line -match "^ALTER TABLE.* PRIMARY KEY")
                {
                    break
                }
                elseif ($line -match "^ALTER TABLE.* ADD UNIQUE")
                {
                    $out += $line -replace "\]|\[", "" -replace " NONCLUSTERED", "" 
                }
                elseif ($line -notmatch "^\s*$")
                {
                    $out += $line -replace "\]|\[", "" -replace "^\s*", "" `
                    -replace " ASC,", ", " -replace " ASC$", "" `
                    <#-replace "\bdbo\.\b", "" #> `
                    -replace " NONCLUSTERED", "" 
                }
                $used = $true
            }
            $block = "$out;`r`ngo`r`n"
            $out
        }
        if ($used)
        {
            "go"
        }
    }
} 
}
```

Você também pode fazer um script completo de um dado banco de dados:

```
Get-ScriptForTable 'localhost'  'MyDB' 'sa' 'toipsecret'  |  Out-File  "C:\temp\Create_commented_tables.sql"
```

Ou um filtro para uma única tabela:

```
Get-ScriptForTable 'localhost'  'MyDB' 'sa' 'toipsecret' 'OnlyThisTable'
```

Além dessas respostas da pergunta "[How do you document your databases?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/515)" tem também o [DB>doc](https://sqldbdoc.codeplex.com/), que é uma ferramenta para documentação gerando para banco de dados Microsoft SQL Server. Ela é uma aplicação de console, usado na linha de comando e controlado por vários switches. Para gerar documentação HTML do banco de dados com uma string de conexão dada:

```
Sqldbdoc "SERVER =. \ SqlExpress; TRUSTED_CONNECTION = yes; DATABASE = AdventureWorks" aw-doc.htm
```

Eu particularmente nunca usei nenhuma dessas ferramentas, quando precisei de uma documentação sobre o banco de dados usei Engenharia Reversa. Com o [Power Designer](http://powerdesigner.de/en/), ele transforma as tabelas do banco de dados em um diagrama.

---

Essas são ferramentas para documentar o banco de dados, para [documentar views, store procedures e funções](https://rodrigopb.wordpress.com/2011/09/27/documentar-vistas-stores-y-funciones-en-sql-server/), você pode definir um comentário com a tag `Descripcion`:

```
-- Descripcion: Deleta por nome de Cliente
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[DeleteByName]
@Name nvarchar(255)
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DELETE FROM CLIENT WHERE NAME = @Name
END
GO
```

Obs.:  Nas views os comentários devem ter o `CREATE/ALTER` antes do `GO`.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[VW_SELLER]
AS
SELECT  *
FROM CLIENT
INNER JOIN SELLER ON CLIENT.ID = SELLER.ID
-- Descripcion: Retorna a informação expandidas dos vendedores
GO
```

O script abaixo obtém a informação da documentação inserida no código. Ele percorre os objetos da base de dados (views, stores procedures, funções) e para cada objeto obtém o código fonte com [sp_helptext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/ms176112.aspx). Com a documentação, mostra o nome do objeto e sua descrição.

```
-- ************************************************************************
-- * Obtém a descrição das tabelas, procedures, views e funções *
-- ************************************************************************
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @DESCRIPCION VARCHAR(4000)
CREATE TABLE #helptext
(
[Text] VARCHAR(4000) NULL
);

DECLARE ShowComentsAll CURSOR
FOR
SELECT sysusers.[name] + '.' + sysobjects.[name] AS FullName
FROM sysobjects
INNER JOIN sysusers ON sysobjects.uid = sysusers.uid
WHERE xtype in ('P', 'V', 'FN')
ORDER BY xtype, FullName

OPEN ShowComentsAll
DECLARE @name VARCHAR(250)

FETCH NEXT FROM ShowComentsAll INTO @name
WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

DELETE #helptext
SET @DESCRIPCION = NULL

INSERT INTO #helptext
exec sp_helptext @name

SELECT @DESCRIPCION = [text]
FROM #helptext
WHERE [text] LIKE '-- Descripcion:%'
IF (@DESCRIPCION IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
PRINT @NAME
PRINT @DESCRIPCION
END

FETCH NEXT FROM ShowComentsAll INTO @name
END
CLOSE ShowComentsAll
DEALLOCATE ShowComentsAll
DROP TABLE #helptext
```

Resultado:

```
dbo.DeleteByName
-- Descripcion: Deleta por nome de Cliente
dbo.VW_SELLER
-- Descripcion: Retorna a informação expandidas dos vendedores
```

Comment: Nãos ei se estou correto, mas aparentemente documentar código SQL é diferente de documentar bancos de dados. Essas ferramentas que você citou parecem ser melhores para o segundo.

Comment: @DanielFalbel, você está correto, editei a resposta.

Comment: Essa ferramenta e muito boa para documentar bancos de dados, criei uma imagem docker para documentar todos os bancos de um servidor
https://github.com/krismorte/database-diagrams